# Error while accessing trystack

Tags: facebook, cloud, openstack

In order to test my trystack access i have used the following credentials:

```
export OS_AUTH_URL="http://8.21.28.222:5000/v2.0"
export OS_TENANT_NAME=facebook100001138064040 
export OS_USERNAME='facebook100001138064040'
export OS_PASSWORD='my facebook password'
```

After that i have stored them in a file named openstack, and then i have used the following commands:

```
source openstack
nova list
```

Even so i had obtained the following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid OpenStack Nova credentials.
```

Now does anyone knows how to solve this mistake. Any help will be most welcome.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys it's a no go. Quoting a friend from the Facebook group:

"We are testing access like this right now, you will use a different password than your FB one. Should have this access available very soon."

If anyone is like me, i guess we will be waiting together.

Thank you for your time.